# Are robotic pollenators being designed?

Tags: mobile-robot

With the bee hive collapses, growers are desperate for pollenation options. Is anyone working on swarms of tiny flying robots to augment the bees? They could look for a certain color, poke around inside the flower for a moment, and move on to the next. When they need recharging, they fly back to their hive (*the same reason bees fly back*).

Of course, replacing germinators that run the seeds through their digestive systems would be a different problem.

Comment: I see that at least [harvard](http://robobees.seas.harvard.edu/) is doing research into such an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Harvard University who are actively working on a [Robobees](http://robobees.seas.harvard.edu/) project which has various goals in mind, one of which is autonomous pollination, they see autonomous pollination as being a couple of decades away yet. They admit that the better solution is to remedy the natural problem of Colony Collapse Disorder. I quote from their website:

*One potential application of micro-robotic "insects" might someday be to artificially pollinate crops. However, we do not see robotic pollination as a wise or viable long-term solution to Colony Collapse Disorder. If robots were used for pollination—and we are at least 20 years away from that possibility— it would only be as a stop-gap measure while a solution to CCD is implemented to restore natural pollinators.*

[More about that here](http://robobees.seas.harvard.edu/robobees-project-and-colony-collapse-disorder-ccd).